# Why would Window.Close event propagate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I ran into a weird case where `Close` event of the child window propagate to the parent window and causes it to close as well.

I made a minimum example as shown below

For `TestWindow` there is nothing but the default WPF window generated by VS

and in `App.xaml.cs` I override the `OnStartup` event and use it as a custom `Main` function

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    TestWindow t = new TestWindow();
    t.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now if you click on the X button to close TestWindow, the application shuts down instead of showing the `MainWindow`. If you comment out `t.ShowDialog` then the `MainWindow` will show just fine. Next if you listen to the `Closing` event of `MainWindow` you will find that it will trigger after the `TestWindow` closes which doesn't seem right to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually *propagating*, WPF runs your first dialog and upon closing notices that the process has no further windows present. WPF posts an application **quit** message for later processing.  In the meantime your code has proceeded to display a further window which when processing the message pump encounters the quit message and so closes the window and terminates your app.

Debug log:

> Information: 0 : App OnStartup
>
> Information: 0 : new MainWindow
>
> Information: 0 : MainWindow closing
>
> Information: 0 : App exiting

To resolve, you need to remove the `StartupUri` and instead handle the `Startup` event.

Change:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfCloseProblem.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCloseProblem"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"> ...
```

...to:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfCloseProblem.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCloseProblem"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Then discard the code on OnStartup and instead define a handler for Startup:

```
//protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
//{
//    base.OnStartup(e);
//
//    TestWindow t = new TestWindow();
//    t.ShowDialog();
//}

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var main = new MainWindow();

    TestWindow t = new TestWindow();
    t.ShowDialog();

    main.Show();
}
```

Previously I was able to confirm that after the dialog closed, `MainWindow` was created; loaded and closed in quick succession.

Comment: We can just add code to `OnStartup`, don't need a separate handler. I like this approach. However it would be perfect if you explain about the App choosing its MainWindow (as I do in my answer). With that added, this is the most perfect answer and I agree that what I suggested about setting the MainWindow explicitly is not as good as this (unless in case `ShowDialog()` is not used).

Comment: Thanks @KingKing. Yes I am at a bit of a loss for the explanation sadly.  I thought it may have been something to do with the first window being shown as a _dialog_ and perhaps when it is closed, WPF goes _"oh there's no more windows, time to exit"_.  I thought about regular Windows where dialogs have their own message pump. Not sure if it is related. Though this is WPF so not sure how similar they are.  I'll continue to investigate.  Have a fine weekend!

Comment: @KingKing possible explanation added

Comment: your explanation about posting WM_QUIT message sounds nice, it's the only way it could work (involving Win32 much) and may be designed specifically for `ShowDialog` (without using `ShowDialog` it behaves normally depending on the `ShutdownMode`).

Comment: I guess that's the closest we can get without looking at the WPF source code. Thanks

Comment: I would to add that if setting `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown`, then the app is always kept alive unless (as its mode name suggests) we use explicit code to shut down the app (the `Shutdown` method).

Comment: @KingKing Yes I like your idea of `ShutdownMode`, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

The way `App` works here is it chooses the first started window as the main window. So in your case, the `TestWindow` will be chosen as the main window. The `ShutdownMode` in your code is somehow set to `OnMainWindowClose`. So after closing `TestWindow`, all child windows (including your `MainWindow`) have their `Closing` fired.

So the problem here is not propagating up, but propagating ***down*** the closing event.

You should not create any window before your main window actually being started first. Or if you want, you can set `ShutdownMode` to `OnLastWindowClose`.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnStartup(e);
  Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
  TestWindow t = new TestWindow();
  t.ShowDialog();
}
```

Or you can set the `MainWindow` explicitly in the constructor of your main window:

```
public MainWindow(){ 
  InitializeComponent();
  Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
}
```

However if using `ShowDialog()`, there is no way for you to set the `MainWindow` explicitly. Because right after closing the `TestWindow` (at that time it's still main window), the whole app will be shutdown.

**Edit**:
I don't find any reference about this but it can be checked and we can be sure about that, here is the debugging:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnStartup(e);
  new TestWindow();//not even need to be shown
  var wm = Application.Current.MainWindow;// points to the new TestWindow
  //If there is not any Window init here, the MainWindow is just null      
}
```

Comment: For the first started window do you mean first initialized one or first one to show?

Comment: @Steve the first one being initialized. I've tried debugging it and the constructor of `MainWindow` is called after `OnStartup()` which means it is called after the `TestWindow()`.

Comment: do you happen to have the source for the first started window = main window part? I would like to read more about it

Comment: It's my assumption. You can test that any way. Such as I've checked that by changing the `ShutdownMode`. If you debug, you can even check the `MainWindow` property of current app.

Comment: So I tried to do Application.Current.MainWindow == this inside MainWindow's constructor, and it returns true which means the MainWindow is passed onto the new Window properly. And since MainWindow is not yet created by the time TestWindow's closing event is fired, I don't think MainWindow would be the child of TestWindow

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure what you meant, I've debugged it (see my edit) and it obviously hooked up somehow and set the `TestWindow` to its `MainWindow` property.

Comment: @Steve by the way, you can read my answer to understand how it behaves like that but the best solution is the answer of ***Micky***. The combination of 2 answers is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I always like to know why things happened instead of just finding a work around. I think you have a good theory but there is something I am having trouble understanding. Basically the flow of the application is like this : TestWindow initialized -> Application.Current.MainWindow set to TestWindow -> TestWindow Close -> MainWindow Class Initialized -> Application.Current.MainWindow set to MainWindow Class -> MainWindow Close event Fired. If TestWindow is the parent of MainWindow then MainWindow should get initialized before TestWindow closes.

Comment: @Steve I'm not so sure about that because it happens only when using `ShowDialog()`. Somehow there is always a callback to shutdown the app. So right at the time closing `TestWindow` (it's still the main window). The callback is queued and executed later. The `MainWindow` is initialized next (because of `StartupUri`) and right after it's done (including registering Closing handler), the callback is executed and closes all windows (and fires the Closing event). I think it's fairly complicated to understand how it hooks up everything in this case.