# Unable to ShowDialog repeatedly

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

In constructor of my `App` class am showing window as dialog repeatedly while it returns true:

```
public App()
{       
    for (;;)
    {
        ...
        var factory = new ControlsFactory<int>();
        var window = factory.CreateWindow(model);
        var result = window.ShowDialog();
        if (!(result ?? false)) return;                
    }
}
```

It shows at first iteration successfully and returns true(I have a button with click handler in it, where I set `DialogResult = true;`), but next time it just returns `false` immediately and loop gets broken. Is there any way to show window as dialog consequentially and infinitely?

Comment: What does `factory.CreateWindow()` look like?  Does it return a new object each time?

Comment: If you don't have any prior windows to this, then WPF will terminate your app after the first `ShowDialog()`.  It thinks you have made a dialog application.  _[Why would Window.Close event propagate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049006/why-would-window-close-event-propagate/33049143#33049143)_

Comment: Post the code for the `Window` class and its `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @Micky yeap just  `return new CommonWindow() { Model = model };`

Comment: @Micky, it doesn't answers my final question, I think

Comment: @ray I don't override `ShowDialog` method and the only code is OK-button click handler where a single line of code is written as described in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set `Application.Current.ShutdownMode` to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`.

MSDN:

> `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`
>
> An application shuts down only when Shutdown is called.

This is because, showing a modal dialog (when it is the only window present) will by default cause an application **quit message** to be posted, thus causing any future windows to **immediately close** before they are shown visually.

Comment: Yeap, it works, thanks! And I probably should read related question attentively